# How do I run a command on a TTY from a SSH session?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, tty

Does anyone know of a way that I could run a command from my ssh session and have it display on tty1?  It seems like I could do that like: `script command >> /dev/tty1`.

However, if I were to do that, and close my terminal it would kill the process wouldn't it?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: "it would kill the process wouldn't it?" It depends on on how the program handles a `SIGHUP`. When you logout `bash` sends a sighup to currently running processes that are direct children of the shell that's exiting. If the process daemonizes itself or ignores the `SIGHUP` (such as if you ran it with the `nohup` command) then the program will continue running and just re-parent to `init`.

Comment: But it's probably also a good idea to let us know why you're wanting to write to tty1 in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spawn your script within a `screen` session. Redirect output to TTY as you proposed. Detach from the screen session and close the terminal. No SIGHUP will be sent so the script should continue to run.

Answer (score 5):

Screen is a bit heavy handed.

A second way is to use the old school method of nohup.

```
nohup script command 2>&1 > /dev/tty1 &
```

The nohup command captures all hangup signals and ignores them, so the the command left after will not receive and there for not stop on closing your terminal.

Comment: What is up with the & charactors?

Comment: The charactors are fine. I hope you've learnt what they mean by now.

Comment: @MarcinKaminski Yea... it seems like forever ago.

Comment: @Questionmark, the ampersand means to run the process in the background.